# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle: Get current user on server side

Tags: symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am using Symfony 3.4 and LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle 2.4. Do you know how to retrieve the user that is accessing the API endpoint?

Normally, I would call `$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();` but that doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: You should be able to just type hint the current user in the controller `public function someAction(UserInterface $user)` if it doesn't work do you get any errors? If nothing helps I'd try going over the configuration steps for LexikJWT again

Answer (score 3):

Advice for you, use **container** key in controller.

Of course, it's better to send the your error here!

**Symfony 4**

```
protected function getCurrentUser()
    {

        if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
            throw new \LogicException('The Security Bundle is not registered in your application.');
        }
        if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
            // e.g. anonymous authentication
            return;
        }
        return $user;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same issue, you can get Id of current user by using :

```
$current_user = $this->getUser();

$id = $current_user->getId();
```

Inside your controller.